# Heroku website won't update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, github, push

I pushed my data to GitHub and then to heroku 25 minutes ago. When I go to my heroku app activity, it clearly got there but my website won't update. I tried it again, my activity says that last deployment happened 4  minutes ago but the website is still the same. My initial deployed was like an hour ago and this was my first update. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I often make the mistake of not pushing my current branch to the Heroku master. Since Heroku is just another git repo, you can push whatever you want up to it, and even use it in lieu of GitHub. But it will only deploy what you push to its `master` branch.

```
git push heroku my-branch:master
```

If you are developing on the master branch, then all you need is

```
git push heroku
```